# How can I set the background color of a row in a table using google apps script in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Doc with a table. I've gotten a script that copies the table and inserts the copy between the first paragraph and the table. I would like the tables to be identical but I can't figure out how to make the header row of the table gray like it is in the original table.

I've figured out how to highlight the text in the header row, but I'm looking to turn the entire row gray.

//Add menu to document

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('New Table')
  .addItem('Add Table', 'addTable')
  .addToUi();
```

}

```
function addTable() {

var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
```

//Add a horizontal rule & line break above existing tables

```
body.insertHorizontalRule(3);
body.insertParagraph(4, ' ');
```

// Create a two-dimensional array containing the cell contents.

```
var cells = [
  ['Week of: Week _'],
  ['Agenda/ Focus for the Week:'],
  ['Notes / Questions:'],
  ['Next Steps / Who’s Responsible?:'],
  ['Progress Toward SMART Goal(s):'],
```

];

// Build a table from the array

```
var table1 = body.insertTable(2,cells);
```

//Set width of the first column

```
table1.setColumnWidth(0, 467);
```

//Set height of first column

```
table1.getRow(1).setMinimumHeight(35);
table1.getRow(2).setMinimumHeight(35);
table1.getRow(3).setMinimumHeight(35);
table1.getRow(4).setMinimumHeight(35);
```

//Set Border color

```
table1.setBorderColor('#000000');
```

//Set style of font in table

```
var style = {};
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = '10';
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;

table1.setAttributes(style);
```

//Set header row style
    var tableHeader = table1.getRow(0);

```
var headerStyle = {};  
headerStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
headerStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = '10';
headerStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = '#BBB9B9';

tableHeader.setAttributes(headerStyle);
```

I want the top row of the new table to be colored gray, but it only highlights the text gray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to try:

```
  tableHeader.getCell(0).setBackgroundColor('#BBB9B9');
```

If the row has multiple columns, you'll need to iterate through them. [Ref docs here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#setBackgroundColor(String)).

Comment: In my special case it was tableHeader.getCell(0,0).setBackgroundColor("#eeeeee")